# Concatenate all files in a directory with specific names

Tags: bash

To concatenate a series of files, one would write:

```
cat file1 file2 ...
```

Now, if in a directory, there are a number of files with 'exon' in their
name, one way to concatenate them is to do:

```
cat exon.file1 exon.file2 ...
```

Is there another way to concatenate files in a directory without writing
every single one after the cat command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `exon.*`:

```
cat exon.*
```

Which will be expanded to:

```
cat exon.file1 exon.file2 ...
```

[Read more about globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs)

As noticed by [@fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) you might want to use:

```
cat *exon*
```

This will expand to all files containing exon in its name, no matter where exactly.

Comment: @fedorqui There is no need in this whole question then.